# How to provide toggle buttons in form?

Tags: html, css, forms

Actually when I create a project, I can assign it to a workgroup by a radio button selection. I would to be able to provide toggle buttons [like that](http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed2/book/HIG.Controls2.html) for this option.

Is there an option or a widget in Symfony2 to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could stick with checkboxes to do something like this:

[Checkbox switches using jQuery](http://devgrow.com/iphone-style-switches/)

The iphone style is quite nice as well:

[iPhone style checkboxes](http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/06/16/iphone-style-checkboxes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you need a Symphony specific solution, as this can be done via CSS only. I wrote a tutorial about how to customize checkboxes and radios with CSS only, as well as create on/off toggle switches. Maybe this helps :) Read it here: http://blog.felixhagspiel.de/index.php/posts/custom-inputs